# Read a table row input values after editing them and clicking somewhere else in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this simple code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function()
{
$("#sme table tr").bind("mouseenter mouseleave", function()
{
    $(this).toggleClass("one");
});
$("#sme table tr").bind("click", function()
{
    $("#sme table tr").removeClass("two");
    $(this).toggleClass("two");
});

$("#sme table tr").bind("dblclick", function()
{
    $.each($(this).find("input"), function(k,v)
{
       $(this).parent().unbind("dblclick");
       $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
});
});
$("#sme table tr").bind("blur", function()
{
    $.each($(this).find("td input"), function(k,v) {
      $(this).attr("readonly","readonly");
});
});
});
</script>
<style type="text/css">
table { border-collapse:collapse;}
table tr td {padding: 6px;}
.one {background-color: yellow;}
.two {background-color: orange;}
input {width:30px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="sme">
<table border="1">
<tr><td>1</td><td><input type="text" value="20" readonly="readonly"/></td><td><input type="text" value="3" readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>2</td><td><input type="text" value="22" readonly="readonly"/></td><td><input type="text" value="3" readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>3</td><td><input type="text" value="23" readonly="readonly"/></td><td><input type="text" value="3" readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
<tr><td>4</td><td><input type="text" value="24" readonly="readonly"/></td><td><input type="text" value="3" readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

or http://jsfiddle.net/x9CMC/ for more reliability.

I did a function which at double click, the `readonly` attribute was removed from all input from that row.

I want to read values (from every cell, no matter if that cell contains input or not) with blur function (means if I click somewhere else, I want to show an alert with all values from that row and add `readonly` to input).

I binded a blur action but it doesn't work properly, something is wrong ...

If I edited the 4th row and I click somewhere else, I want to show alert like this `4, new value edited by me, new value edited by me`.

How ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/ZcMCg/1

The blur action didn't work because it was the inputs that had focus, not the row.
Unlike mouseenter/mouseleave focus and blur events do not bubble (but don't take my word for it, I just woke up).

As your table gets bigger you may want to have a look at jQuery's event delegation (delegate(), or on() with an extra selector passed in the 1.7 API) by the way.

Answer (score 0):

You should work with custom events here, this makes your life much easier.

Consider this jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#sme table tr")
    .hover(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("hl");
    })
    .bind("lock", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("open")
        .find("input").attr("readonly", "readonly");
    })
    .bind("unlock", function() {
        $(this).addClass("open")
        .find("input").removeAttr("readonly")
        .first().focus();
    })
    .dblclick(function() {
        $(this).trigger(
          $(this).is(".open") ? "lock" : "unlock"
        )
        .siblings("tr.open").trigger("lock");
    });
});
```

(see it in action in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tomalak/x9CMC/1/))

What's happening here is:

- I've created two custom events that *"lock"* and *"unlock"* an individual row. 
  They handle changing the `<tr>` CSS class and making the `<input>` elements in a row read-only or not
- I've hooked triggering these events to the double click on a row. Double-clicking a locked row unlocks it and vice-versa (that's what `trigger()` does).

As you can see, the code becomes much cleaner once you separate the steps involved in editing a row from each other.

Note:

- There is no need to repeat the same selector (in your case `$("#sme table tr")` and `$(this)`) again and again. Just chain more methods to a single selector, like I did.
- There is no `blur` event for `<tr>` elements. Only form elements that can have `focus` can `blur`.
- There is no need to call `each()` on a selector. Everything you do to it will automatically be done to all selected elements. For example: `$("a").hide()` will hide each `<a>` on the entire page.
- The event that catches `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` is called `hover` in jQuery.
- There is no need to call `bind()`, most jQuery events have native handlers. For example `bind("click", function() {})` is equivalent to `click(function() {})`